# How can we make a string in to array without keys

Tags: php, arrays

Here am getting array like this

```
array:3 [
0 => "Monthly Supplier Report"
1 => " Retailer Report"
2 => " Weekly Supplier Report"
]
```

and i want to convert it into like this

```
array:3 ["Monthly Supplier Report"," Retailer Report"," Weekly Supplier Report"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Array are always indexed if you don't specify index PHP assumes integers as index starting from 0 and 1 as increment.